# Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address - raspberry pi 3b+

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver, raspbian

I have written a simple kernel module, which is generating segmentation fault whenever I try to open, read or write into the module. The open, read and write functions does nothing but prints a message. I did a search but could not find the solution. Please help. Below is the dmesg output when trying to write.

```
Platform : Raspberry Pi 3b+ , Raspbian 4.19.58-v7+


There is no issue with the code since i have executed it on my Ubuntu PC and it works perfectly fine.
```

[screenshot of dmesg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PrWd.jpg)

Comment: Is your module called "kmodule"? That was the last module unloaded, so perhaps it didn't clean itself up properly.

Comment: yes, kmodule is the one i have developed. What cleanup is required to fix the problem ?

Comment: Cleanup: If the module init function detects an error and returns a negative error code, it needs to undo everything up to the point that the error occurred. If the module init function returns 0 (success),  the module exit function needs to undo everything that the module init function did. The same sort of thing applies to device probe and remove functions.